# Strange VNC Error Appears to Be Replicating Processes?

Tags: vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I'm running vnc into a server at work. It runs and doesn't crash, and I am able to use the terminal and whatever else, but the mouse stays in a circular 'thinking about it' state and I see the following at the bottom in the taskbar.

[image: Problem: Keeps scrolling across but never crashes.]

Anyone else who uses vnc to access the server sees the same behavior. Does anyone know a possible cause? Can provide more details if required! Just wondering if anyone has seen similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if the window list program was the culprit. Somehow it got stuck in a loop opening itself, and when closed, would reload itself almost immediately. Forcing a stop by killing the process(es) and denying a reload, and then rebooting the machine worked for me.

ps -ef | grep wmctrl

kill INSERT_PID_HERE